# Join two dataframes with random in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes Events and address.

**Events:**

```txt
Eent_id |Type|Event_date
AA-XX-BB|SMS |1613693293023
AA-BB-DD|CALL|1613693295039
```

**Address:**

```txt
Postcode|CityName
RG15NL  |Reading
SL34AD  |Slough
```

I want to enrich the event dataset by adding address and postcode values.

As there is no common key between these two sets, am just looking for a solution to pick the random row from address file and attach to event file.

Being this a sample data, I am ok to take any random row from address file and attach to events file.

Please let me know if there a way I can achieve this as there is no common key between the two datasets.

Comment: Thanks. Some extend it answers. If i understood correct, they are creating index and joining on index but in my scenario both the dataframes will not have same number of rows so join on index will not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the same number of rows, you can try to do a cross join then pick one address for each `event_id` using `row_number` over a partition ordered randomly:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val result = df.crossJoin(address_df).withColumn(
    "rn",
    row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("Eent_id").orderBy(rand()))
  ).filter("rn = 1").drop("rn")

result.show
//+--------+----+-------------+--------+--------+
//| Eent_id|Type|   Event_date|Postcode|CityName|
//+--------+----+-------------+--------+--------+
//|AA-XX-BB| SMS|1613693293023|  SL34AD|  Slough|
//|AA-BB-DD|CALL|1613693295039|  SL34AD|  Slough|
//+--------+----+-------------+--------+--------+
```